# ndk-build error using cygwin

Tags: android, android-ndk, cygwin, vuforia

I installed ndk and vuforia. The ndk path is `C:\Development\Android\android-ndk-r9b` then set this path to system variable. The cygwin path is `C:\cygwin\bin` then set this path to system variable. The vuforia path also correct. When build the sample ndk examples and when i run the vuforia sample i'm getting below error in cygwin command window. I can't run my project using ndk-build

```
Arun@Arun-PC ~
$ cd D:\\AugmentedReality\\vuforia\\vuforia-sdk-android-2-5-7\\samples\\ImageTargets-2-6-7

Arun@Arun-PC /cygdrive/d/AugmentedReality/vuforia/vuforia-sdk-android-2-5-7/samples/ImageTargets-2-6-7
$ ndk-build
[armeabi] Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.6] libs/armeabi/gdbserver
[armeabi] Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi/gdb.setup
[armeabi-v7a] Gdbserver      : [arm-linux-androideabi-4.6] libs/armeabi-v7a/gdbserver
[armeabi-v7a] Gdbsetup       : libs/armeabi-v7a/gdb.setup
[armeabi] Compile++ arm  : ImageTargets <= ImageTargets.cpp
/bin/sh: /cygdrive/c/Development/Android/android-ndk-r9b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++: No such file or directory
/cygdrive/c/Development/Android/android-ndk-r9b/build/core/build-binary.mk:386: recipe for target 'obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/ImageTargets/ImageTargets.o' failed
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/ImageTargets/ImageTargets.o] Error 127
```

Comment: Have you tried running the Windows command line version of NDK-BUILD instead of the Cygwin script? You no longer need Cygwin to build for the NDK.

Comment: I used same command in windows command line. but ndk-build is not recognized internal or external command error.

Comment: If ndk-build is not recognized, then you need to add the NDK directory to the system path. You can also type the whole thing: C:\Development\Android\android-ndk-r9b\ndk-build.

Comment: Is i nedd to set my NDK path to system variable is C:Developement/android-ndk-r9b/ndk-build? then i should run in cygwin command cd C:Developement/android-ndk-r9b/ndk-build?

Comment: You need to be in your JNI directory and run the ndk-build command. If the NDK is in your system PATH you can just execute ndk-build; if not, then you need to specify the full name (e.g. c:\.......\ndk-build)

Comment: NDK r9b does not work well with cygwin. You don't need to set system path,  simply run `C:\Development\Android\android-ndk-r9b\ndk-build.cmd` in your project directory. If you cannot find `C:\Development\Android\android-ndk-r9b\ndk-build.cmd`, your NDK installation is wrong.

Comment: How to run sample project? This is sample project directory: D:\\AugmentedReality\\vuforia\\vuforia-sdk-android-2-5-7\\samples\\ImageTargets-2-6-7

Comment: when i run the command: the system is cannot find the path. But ndk path is proper in directory.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a lot of issues building Android NDK projects on Windows. Most places suggested using cygwin, I found a solution that didn't need it and wrote up a blog post on it: http://ghoofman.com/android-ndk/

Hope that helps.